# Не получается сделать hamburger

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.a');
var listItem = document.querySelector('.list');


a.onclick = function() {
  listItem.classList.toggle('lis');
  console.log(listItem);
}
```

```css
.header{
  background-color: #263658
}
 
.nav{
  display: -webkit-flex
 display: -moz-flex
 display: -ms-flex
 display: -o-flex
 display: flex
 align-items: center
 justify-content: center
}
 
.a{
 // outline: 1px solid red
 // color: #
 // background-color: #fff
 // border: 1px solid red
  margin-right: 7%
}

 
.list{
  display: -webkit-flex
 display: -moz-flex
 display: -ms-flex
 display: -o-flex
 display: flex
 align-items: center
 justify-content: center
 margin: 10px 0
 list-style-type: none
 padding-left: 0
}
 
.list-item{
   margin-left: 3%
}
.list-item .a{
    color: #fff
  font-family: Montserrat
  font-size: 14px
  font-weight: 400
  text-decoration: none
  text-align: center
  white-space: nowrap
}
.list-item:first-child{
  margin-left: 2%
}
  

 
// .list-item:last-child
//  margin-left: 0
.button{
  border-radius: 6px
 background-color: #fd5f00
 width: 210px
 display: -webkit-flex
 display: -moz-flex
 display: -ms-flex
 display: -o-flex
 display: flex
 align-items: center
 justify-content: center
 font-weight: 700
 padding: 10px 33px
}

 
.lis{
  display: block
}
 
.bg{
  background-image: url('../img/bg.png')
 background-size: cover
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .9)
 min-height: 440px
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="menu">
          <nav class="nav">
            <a class="a">
              <i class="fas fa-bars hamburger">class="a"</i>
            </a>
            <ul class="list">
              <!-- <li class="list-item">
              <a><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
            </li> -->
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">О центре</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">Расписание</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">Тренинги</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">Тренеры</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">Отзывы</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">Аренда залов</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#">Контакты</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item button">
                <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @Air а мобильной верстке был hamburger  при клике появлялось и исчезало меню

Comment: @Air сейчас покажу картинку

Comment: @Air  не могу я пишу на sass а тут css :(((

Comment: @Air сайт не понимает sass не могу показать

Comment: @Air  вдруг страшно говорить получится говнокод ...

Comment: @Air :((( заказчик волк

Comment: @Air все равно спасибо дядя

Comment: @Air у меня на разрешении 750 и ниже  не работает; почему то

Comment: Покажите ваш код, что за детский сад. Скомпилировать `sass` дело 10 секунд.

Comment: @E_K  все теперь все заработало дядя